# File uploads in Heroku deployment with Django

Tags: django, heroku, django-deployment

So I was finally able to set up local + prod test project I'm working on.

```
# wsgi.py 
from dj_static import Cling, MediaCling

application = Cling(MediaCling(get_wsgi_application()))
application = DjangoWhiteNoise(application)
```

I set up static files using whitenoise (without any problems) and media (file uploads) using [dj_static](https://github.com/kennethreitz/dj-static) and Postgres for local + prod. Everything works fine at first... static files, file uploads.

But after the Heroku dynos restart I lose all the file uploads. My question is, --- Since I'm serving the media files from the Django app instead of something like S3, does the dyno restart wipe all that out too?

PS: I'm aware I can do this with AWS, etc, but I just want to know if thats the reason I'm losing all the uploads.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Since I'm serving the media files from the Django app instead of something like S3, does the dyno restart wipe all that out too?

Yes!. That's right. According to the [Heroku docs](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#ephemeral-filesystem):

> Each dyno gets its own ephemeral filesystem, with a fresh copy of the most recently deployed code.

See, also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36631648/media-files-on-heroku) answer and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41474150/using-heroku-for-django-media-files) answer.

Conclusion: For media files (the uploaded ones), you must use some external service (like S3 or something). `whitenoise` is just for static files. See [here](http://whitenoise.evans.io/en/stable/django.html#serving-media-files) why whitenoise is not suitable for serving user-uploaded (media) files.

Comment: Great, I wanted to be sure of all this. Thanks !