# Uploaded medias not found in a deployed heroku app

Tags: heroku, django-rest-framework

I have a DjangoRest/ Vue.js app.
I have endpoints where I upload users pictures.
In production my urls were :  `"picture": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/media/image.jpg"`
Now with my app deployed on Heroku it's:  `"picture":` `"https://myapp.herokuapp.com/media/image.jpg",`
But as I try to GET an uploaded picture, I get a

> Not Found The requested resource was not found on this server.

In my settings.py I have:

```
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, '..', 'uploaded_media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

And in my urls.py:

```
urlpatterrns[] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [File uploads in Heroku deployment with Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43422704/file-uploads-in-heroku-deployment-with-django)

Comment: Yes. I will have to store them on amazons3